# LINQPad crashes every time a query is run with a .NET Runtime exception

Tags: .net, crash, linqpad

Every time I run even the simplest of queries in LINQPad it crashes.

I have tried all the obvious stuff, from rebooting the machine to getting the latest versions etc. The only recent change on the system has been installing VS2010 SP1.

Any ideas on how to get it back up and running, or what the root of the problem could be? The two Events are below:

**Application Error**

> Faulting application name: LINQPad.exe, version: 4.31.0.0, time stamp: 0x4cfb29be
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7bafa
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000b727
>
> Faulting process id: 0x18d8
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cc2f2350f6d975
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\LINQPad4\LINQPad.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: 992bfc75-9b16-11e0-9419-b8ac6f2e5a9a

**.NET Runtime Error**

> Application: LINQPad.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>
> Stack:
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType)
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)
>
> at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(System.Object)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)
>
> at LINQPad.UI.QueryControl._query_QueryStarted(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
>
> at LINQPad.Query.OnQueryStarted()
>
> at LINQPad.Query.Run(System.String)
>
> at LINQPad.Query.Run()
>
> at LINQPad.UI.QueryControl.Run()
>
> at LINQPad.UI.QueryControl.btnExecute_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
>
> at LINQPad.UI.ImageButton.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons, Int32)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
>
> at LINQPad.Program.Run(System.String, Boolean, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, System.String)
>
> at LINQPad.Program.Go(System.String[])
>
> at LINQPad.Program.Start(System.String[])
>
> at LINQPad.ProgramStarter.Run(System.String[])
>
> at LINQPad.Loader.Main(System.String[])

Comment: Have you ever changed the system "caspol" security settings?

Comment: Your error is related to a stackoverflow exception. Trace it down and ask the author to write better code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something bad is going on in the .NET Framework or the environment.

The last LINQPad method in the stacktrace is exception-handled, so it is very odd. You might like to try a recent experimental build - coincidentally, it no longer has the method that appears in the stack trace. I suspect you'll get an error somewhere else; maybe the diagnostics will be more informative:

http://www.linqpad.net/special/LINQPad4.zip

Comment: Thanks, it was a .NET issue, not just LINQPad.

Comment: @h_a_z_ what was the issue? ;-)